# How can i get the the width for jQuery cycle's container the same as its next slide width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, width, cycle

i'll try to be more specific:

i have this html markup snippet:

```
<div id="slider">
<ul>
<li>first slide</li>
<li>secondth slide</li>
<li>third slide</li>
<li>fourth slide</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and this js snipett to activate cycle

```
$('#slider ul').cycle({ 
    easing: 'easeInBounce',
    fx: 'scrollUp',
    speed:400,
    timeout:5000
});
```

now id like to have the #slider ul width auto calculated the same as its ul li elements.

Hope you guys understand what i mean!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

Ok, so you could use before ( or after callback):

Html:

```
Ul width: <input type="text" id="ulwidth" />
<div id="slider">
<ul>
<li style="width: 150px">first slide</li>
<li style="width: 230px">secondth slide</li>
<li>third slide</li>
<li>fourth slide</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And JS:

```
$('#slider ul').cycle({ 
    fx: 'fade',
    before: function(curr, next, option){ // or after: function...
           //console.log(curr.style.width);
           var w = curr.style.width; // or next.style.width
           $('#slider ul').css({'width': w});
           $('#ulwidth').val($('#slider ul').width());
    }
});
```

This could fit the ul width based on next or current li (after or before use): [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alex_ball/TkNWK/4/)

Comment: the problem is just this, id like to have the ul container the same width of each slide, for example, if the first li slide is 125px, the ul width is the same, and so...

Comment: @AntonioCapuozzo ah ok, now i m away, when come back i try again, i m sorry

Comment: @AntonioCapuozzo hi antonio, see the new answer, is what you want?

Comment: yes it is! Thank you so much, ill try to set it up and i'll let u know if this will fits perfectly :) Thank you again!